# Request is taking time to hit the reactive api

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient, reactive

I have 2 java microservices with below endpoints. Service A calls service B to get user details.
From the zipkin traces i was able to figure out that the complete call is taking 450ms in which Service B took 50ms.
Also, the api of Service A was hit after 200ms.
So the bifurcation of time is as below:
200ms + ServiceA(200ms) + ServiceB(50ms). I am not sure why and where is the initial 200ms going.

1. spring reactive (Service A)
   endpoint -> api/v1/users/{userId}         - took 200+200ms
2. spring non reactive (Service B)
   endpoint -> api/v1/users/{userId}         - took 50ms

   @GetMapping(value = "/users/{userId}")
   public Mono getUser(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
   return userService.getUser(userId);
   }

Comment: You won't get a better in non-blocking IO architecture through analysis single API with single user. Try by adding concurrent requests using more users and stimulate the performance.

Comment: I have no doubt regarding performance here. I am aware that non blocking will perform better with concurrent request. Just wanted to know what is taking 200ms before api call. Is it spring? Can i debug with any tool that where is this time going?